# In which direction will air flow?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, pressure, surface-tension

Here is a problem: [image]

I am having trouble with deciding between choices B and D. The sub-hemispherical bubble will have lesser volume than the hemispherical one for a given radius of the tube, and therefore Boyle's Law dictates that air will flow from end 2 to 1.
Another explanation I can think of is the following: The excess pressure in a soap bubble due to surface tension is inversely proportional to the radius of curvature, which is greater for the sub-hemispherical bubble. According to this reasoning air will flow from end 1 to 2.
Which explanation is correct and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P_i = P_o+4\frac{\gamma}{r}$$

Where $\gamma$ is the surface tension, and $r$ is the radius of the bubble.

As $r_2$ > $r_1$, $P_2$ < $P_1$. Therefore, air will flow from end 1 to end 2.

Boyle's law states the relationship between pressure and volume of a fixed quantity of a gas at a fixed temperature and is not applicable in this case. It is not right to assume that the amount of air on both sides of the valve is the same.

Comment: If it was mentioned in the problem that the amount of gas on either side of the valve is the same, would the answer still be decided by excess pressure? Why or why not?

Comment: That wouldn't happen. Unless there were a temperature difference, the volumes would be the same. So you would essentially get the same radius bubbles on both sides.

Comment: This very much a HW&E type question. You shouldn't provide a full answer.

Comment: @Gert OP had a genuine question and tried to attempt the question and provided their reasoning. I believe it was worth clearing the confusion.